# "Cannot initialise printer" error on Qucken 2000 under Windows-10 (W10)

Tags: windows-10, printing, quicken

For years, we have used Quicken 2000 Deluxe for our personal accounting at home.  We had difficulty when we tried to install it on a new W10 computer, but we eventually found a way to get it installed, based on helpful posts like this one...
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/please-can-you-help-me-i-have-an-old-programmes/439fc67f-ee36-4cd5-ab34-e301299890bf?page=2

Now it mostly works on W10, but with a couple of quirks.

1. The window frame is mostly blank when it first loads up and only fills in as we roll the mouse over it, or as we marginally change the size.  Maximising and restoring always does the trick.  I never found a proper solution to this.  If you have, please share.
2. Printing became a problem recently.  We keep getting a message that saying "cannot initialise printer".  Very annoying and leading to using cut and pasted into another a text document or spreadsheet - very tedious.
3. Printer Setup function on the menu does nothing at all.  No pop up, nothing.

Today I decided we had to find a proper solution to the printing issue. I have so far found nothing on StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am answering my own question.  I'm hoping to save others from the tedious search that was only satisfied when I found a buried response elsewhere...

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/quicken-2000-on-windows-10/f8e4420e-8148-4e31-9e9b-c1a04ada2285?page=2

In the reviews, there is a reply from Jim70P, to whom I am very grateful.  It reads

"Not sure why you can't print to "Microsoft Print to PDF", but quicken stores its available printer information in the file "WPR.DAT" which should be in the Quicken directory/folder. To update the list of available printers backup your Quicken directory then rename WPR.DAT to something else such as "WPR.OLD" then rerun Quicken. The file WPR.DAT should be regenerated and all available system printers should become available to the program.
Hope this helps."

All I did was

1. Close Quicken
2. Go to the C:\Quickenw folder
3. renamed WPR.DAT to oldWPR.DAT and
4. Restarted Quicken
   Magically, Print worked, as did Printer Setup.